# grouping and showing a value in a column

Tags: mysql

[image][image: Data]

There is  a requirement where i need to create a column and show status as IDAHE or EPS or IDAHE/EPS. In the picture for transaction ID 38405 I see is_idahe column as  1 and 0. if i see 1 and 0 for a transaction id then i need to show the status as "IDAHE/EPS". For 38406, is_idahe column has two rows of 1 , then i need to show as "IDAHE". if its just 0 then i have to show as "EPS". How do i achieve it ?

Im new to MYSQL. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT transaction_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
                     CASE WHEN is_idahe 
                          THEN 'IDAHE' 
                          ELSE 'EPS' END
                     ORDER BY is_idahe DESC
                     SEPARATOR '/') output
FROM source_table
GROUP BY transaction_id
```

CASE converts 1s to `'IDAHE'` and 0s to `'EPS'`.

DISTINCT removes duplicates.

Then, if there is 2 values, they're concatenated with proper ordering and separator, else single value is returned.

[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4d7636821008bf52acbad445efb6c6a)

Comment: is it suppose to be is_idahe after when ?

Comment: @siddharththiagarajan I cannot understand your question.

Comment: @siddharththiagarajan Fiddle added.

Comment: @siddharththiagarajan The column value is investigated directly. When the column has the value `1` it is treated as TRUE. `0` as FALSE respectively. So if `is_idahe = 1` then `THEN` alternative is selected, and when `is_idahe = 0` then `ESLE` alternative is selected. Of course you may use `WHEN is_idahe = 1` - but this will be excess compare only, and no profit.

Comment: is_idahe column might come as null. On such instances it has to be null. how can i control that scenario ?

Comment: @siddharththiagarajan NULLs will be treated as FALSE (as 'EPS'). If you need to skip them at all then simply add `WHERE is_idahe IS NOT NULL` before GROUP BY.

Comment: @siddharththiagarajan *On such instances it has to be null.* Absolutely unclear. 1s, 0s and NULLS may produce 7 different combinations. Specify the result for each of them.

Comment: I have added one more picture where transaction_id 38172 has is_idahe as null. i want the 38172 upon grouping to show NULL

Comment: @siddharththiagarajan Look this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=728c115505141ae3380bc72dd43abd35). If the output is not one you need then add this link and desired output for this data (as formatted textual table) into your question as an update.